# Blank space after floated elements in horizontal scrolling div

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-float

I am trying to make a horizontally scrolling div with a series of videos floated next to each other, with the user scrolling across to see more videos.  Everything is working, except there is a huge amount of empty space after the last video, nearly doubling the size of the scrolling div.  I have tried changing the width of the div, changing the right margin/padding, etc. but to no avail.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

The HTML:

```
<div id="work_text">
    <div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title"><h2>SALVATION (Official Trailer)</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65980573?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title_2"><h2>DIESEL BLACK GOLD<br />AUTUMN WINTER 2013/14</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65979791?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title"><h2>Extreme Measures (BULLETT TV)</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65977965?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title"><h2>License To Ill (BULLETT TV)</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65976653?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title"><h2>SALVATION</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65972978?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title_2"><h2>Nico Amarca<br />Cinematography Reel 2013</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/63985060?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="work_post"><div class="work_title"><h2>The Savior</h2></div><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/58233834?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=979999" width="478" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#work_text {
height:450px;
width: 880px;
overflow: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-left: 2px;
}

#work_text div {
width:4690px; /*this value=6x[video width(640px) plus right margin width(30px)] + 478px or + 670px = 4498px or 4690px */
}

#work_text div.work_post {
width:670px;
height:360px;
float:left;
}

#work_text div.work_post_full {
width:478px;
height:360px;
float: left;
}

#work_text div.work_title {
height: 45px;
padding-top: 15px;
}

#work_text div.work_title_2 {
height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#work_text div {
```

should be

```
#work_text > div {
```

Otherwise the all `div` elements inherit that huge width. (JSFiddle: [yours](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/DEJ2V/), [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/DEJ2V/1/).)

Also, your last video is only width `480px` while all the other ones are `640px`, so that leaves a little extra space there. I'd suggest adding specific CSS to make that last `div` smaller.